# Avoid printing notation in Coq with Proof General

Tags: coq, proof-general

In lecture 6 of the DeepSpec 2018, the lecturer Checks the definition of

```
string_dec
```

obtaining:

```
string_dec
     : forall s1 s2 : string, {s1 = s2} + {s1 <> s2}
```

Then he goes on to see the definition  of +, but before, he disables in CoqIde the printing of notation. So that sumbool is printed. This last symbol can be checked.

How can I do the same thing with Proof General?

Comment: what is `notation` in coq?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the menu, `Coq > OPTIONS > Set Printing All`.

You can also issue the command directly, typing `Set Printing All.` and evaluating it in your buffer before running the Check command. This also gives you access to `Unset Printing Notations` to only disable printing notations (which is something you can do with the menu in CoqIDE). When you're done you can just delete this command, which will undo its effect.

Finally, you can also directly use `Coq > OTHER QUERIES > Check (show all)` on `string_dec`.

Comment: Unset Printing Notations, perhaps?

Comment: what is `notation` in coq?